# Why I get "Cannot Get /" when running NextJS app

Tags: next.js

After **create-next-app** and doing "`npm run dev`" browsing `http://localhost:300` I get:

> Cannot get /

Why is that?

Comment: Sure you didn't forget a 0, eg `http://localhost:3000` ? What does npm say ?

Comment: of course, the response "cannot get /" say the app is running. but it doesn't show the main page. npm say this: 
"ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\yigo\Desktop\next\abc-app\.env.development
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\yigo\Desktop\next\abc-app\.env
warn  - React 17.0.1 or newer will be required to leverage all of the upcoming features in Next.js 11. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-version
info  - Using webpack 4. ....
event - compiled successfully"

Comment: If you're actually accessing `http://localhost:3000` you might want to update your question, it's a bit misleading otherwise.

Comment: It doesn' t work with Chrome and Edge, but it works with Firefox !

Comment: I don't know why but Rodrigo is right!!! I can't run it on chrome or Edge, but it works on Firefox